# Excel: Convert yyyymmwwdd timestamp to calendar date

Tags: excel, date

I'm working with a dataset that uses an interesting timestamp of yyyymmwwdd, where:

- yyyy = year (2018, 2017, ...)
- mm = month (01-12)
- ww = week of month (01-05)
- dd = day of week (01-07)

The week starts on Monday, and week 1 of a month has the first Monday of that month. Some examples:

- 2018070503 is Wednesday, August 1, 2018.
- 2018080201 is Monday, August 13, 2018.
- 2018120502 is Tuesday, January 1, 2019.

How can I convert these to normal calendar dates?

I've tried this (assuming the timestamp is in A2):

```
=DATE(VALUE(LEFT(A2,4)),1,1) + ((WEEKNUM(DATE(VALUE(LEFT(A2,4)),VALUE(MID(A2,5,2)),1),11) + VALUE(MID(A2,7,2))-1-1)*7) + (VALUE(RIGHT(A2,2))-1)
```

but it doesn't handle year changes correctly (and it seems clumsy in general).

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works by adding the correct number of days from the first Monday on the month and year.

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,5,2),8)-WEEKDAY(DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,5,2),6))+MID(A1,7,2)*7+RIGHT(A1,2)-8
```

[image]